# weekly report without data envirnment vb 6.0

Tags: vb6

Dear Friends:
I have developed a database using SQL Server 2005 and VB 6.0. Now I want to design a report without data environment. I have the following fields in the table:
Table Name: BusinessBySales
Files: SalesID, BusinessDate, BusinessType, BusinessAmt

My BusinessType records like: FDR, CD, SB, Auto Loan, Home Loan

```
 - SalesID BusinessDate BusinessType  BusinessAmt
 - 1 01/01/2010 SB 1200000
 - 2 02/01/2010 SB 2000000
 - 3 02/01/2010 CD 3000000
 - 4 04/01/2010 Car Loan 1400000
 - 5 08/01/2010 Home Loan 7500000
 - 6 12/01/2010 FDR 3000000
```

### ---

From the above record I want to design a report for a particular month like below

```
Week BusinessType NoOfBus Amount
1st SB 2 3200000
CD 1 3000000
Car Loan 1 1400000
2nd Home Loan 1 7500000
FDR 2 4000000
like 3rd and 4th week also
```

Pls suggest me for doing that report

Thanks

Comment: Have you heard of Crystal Reports? It's very likely that it came with your copy of VB 6, and it makes this kind of task much simpler than doing it by hand.